# Use RAII for writing end of file marker?

Tags: c++, exception, destructor, raii

I'm creating a file format where I'd like to write an explicit message into the file indicating that the writer ran to completion. I've had problems in the past with generating files where the generating program crashed and the file was truncated without me realizing, since without an explicit marker there's no way for reading programs to detect a file is incomplete.

So I have a class that is used for writing these files. Now usually if you have an "open" operation and a "close" operation you want to use RAII, so I would put the code to write the end of file marker in the destructor. This way the user can't forget. But in a situation where writing doesn't complete because an exception is thrown the destructor will still be run -- in which case we don't want to write the message so readers will know the file is incomplete.

This seems like something that could happen any time there's a "commit" sort of operation. You want RAII so you can't forget to commit, but you also don't want to commit when an exception occurs. The temptation here is to use std::uncaught_exceptions, but I think that's a code smell.

What's the usual solution to this? Just require that people remember? I'm concerned this will be a stumbling block everytime someone tries to use my API.

Comment: Herb Sutter has a good article on the subject. http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm Basically his recommendation is to force the user to explicitly close (commit) the file. Otherwise its an valid.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this problem is to implement a simple framing system where you can define a header that is only filled in completely at the end of the write. Include a SHA256 hash to make the header useful for verifying the contents of the file. This is usually a lot more convenient than having to read bytes at the end of a file.

In terms of implementation you write out a header with some fields deliberately zeroed out, write the contents of the payload while feeding that data through your hashing method, and then seek back to the header and re-write that with the final values. The file starts out in an obviously invalid state and ends up valid *only* if everything ran to completion.

You could wrap up all of this in a stream handle that handles the implementation details so as far as the calling code is concerned it's just opening a regular file. Your reading version would throw an exception if the header is incomplete or invalid.

Comment: If I understand right it sounds like this just kicks the can down the road. Either the destructor contains the code that seeks back to the front of the file to fill in the header, or the user has to call an explicit method to do so, and we're back to square one.

Comment: Why would you say that? You can have it both ways: An optional method to force-close the file and finalize the header, or a destructor method that does it if it hasn't been done already. That fits in with RAII quite neatly when you have the constructor cleanly open the file, and the destructor handle any necessary finalization.

Comment: The issue is an interaction between exceptions, that commiting must happen in the error-free case, and that requiring the user to manually call commit is error prone. If you have the manual method, they will often forget to call it. If you do work in the destructor, without using std::uncaught_exception you can't tell why you're in the destructor (if an exception was thrown you *don't want to write the marker*, so that consumers will know the file is incomplete).

Comment: You could make it commit by default, and leave it up to the user to abort the commit manually if necessary in their exception handler. That is you either need to imply success by default and signal failure manually, or failure by default and signal success manually. Failure by default is easier to detect when testing code. You're correct that the destructor has no reason to know why it's firing, exception or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, it seems like RAII would work fine if you add a `commit` method which the user of your class calls when they are done writing to a file.

```
class MyFileFormat {
public:
    MyFileFormat() : committed_(false) {}
    ~MyFileFormat() {
        if (committed_) {
            // write the completion footer (I hope this doesn't throw!)
        }
        // close the underlying stream...
    }

    bool open(const std::string& path) {
        committed_ = false;
        // open the underlying stream...
    }

    bool commit() {
        committed_ = true;
    }
};
```

The onus is on the user to call `commit` when they're done, but at least you can be sure that resources get closed.

For a more general pattern for cases like this, take a look at [ScopeGuards](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758).

ScopeGuards would move the responsibility for cleanup out of your class, and can be used to specify an arbitrary "cleanup" callback in the event that the ScopeGuard goes out of scope and is destroyed before being explicitly dismissed. In your case, you might extend the idea to support callback for both failure-cleanup (e.g. close file handles), and success-cleanup (e.g. write completion footer and close file handles).

Comment: What I'm trying to ask in the question basically is if you can have your cake and eat it too -- not require the user to remember to call a commit method and still have safety. I didn't consider having the commit defer taking any action until the destructor, but I don't see any benefit to that.

Comment: I see, yes - this doesn't answer that question. And in fact, now that I look at it, it seems like deferring the commit action to the destructor is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've handled situations like that by writing to a temporary file.  Even if you're appending to a file, append to a temporary copy of the file.

In your destructor, you can check [std::uncaught_exception()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) to decide whether your temporary file should be moved to its intended location.